# How to show products from subcategories in a category page

Tags: category-products, category-attribute, list.phtml, category-listing, list-view

I need to list products in a category page sorted by subcategory with respective subcategory name before the products. With static blocks I can display the name of the subcategory on the category page but I cannot list the products.
Any pointers?

Comment: You need to do custom code for this, used any .phtml file and in that do code according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Without touching the code. I have created a static block where I entered all my subcategories as follows with respective headings:

```
    {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="ID_OF_SUBCATEGORY" 
    template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="3" 
    products_count="10"}}
```

Then I went to my category and in display settings: Display mode => Products only and CMS Block => the name of my new cms block.